# MongoDB Compass multiply counts on one result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'd like to ask you for help.
I have a MongoDB collection, here's a simplified example.

| date | user |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-09-25 | A |
| 2022-09-25 | A |
| 2022-09-25 | B |
| 2022-09-26 | A |
| 2022-09-26 | A |
| 2022-09-27 | A |
| 2022-09-27 | B |
| 2022-09-27 | B |
| 2022-09-27 | B |

And I need to create a query in MongoDB Compass to get the data in the following structure (where each row is one individual document):

| date | entries | uniqueUsers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-25 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-09-26 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-09-27 | 4 | 2 |

Is it possible (and how) to create one pipeline in MongoDB Compass to achieve such a result?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `$group` with `$addToSet` on aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: "$date",
      users: {$addToSet: "$user"},
      entries: {$sum: 1}
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      date: "$_id",
      entries: 1,
      uniqueUsers: {$size: "$users"},
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1RKk0UQcUTc)

Comment: It works! Thank you, nimrod serok very much.
This is my first week of working at MongoDB and this, as I can see, simple solution was very difficult to me :)